# CMOS ICs Characteristic Query

Tags: digital-logic

I was going through the book for the difference between TTL and CMOS. What does the term high component density means in CMOS ICs?
As writtern CMOS has "high component density."

Answer (score 3):

It simply means that in CMOS technology you can fit more (much more) components on a chip of a certain size than you can in TTL technology.

To illustrate this: the chips inside your smartphone are almost exclusively build in CMOS technology. If these were build using TTL technology your smartphone would be the size of a refrigerator and you would also need a battery the size of a car battery to power it.

Comment: A really comprehensive answer! Thank you! It really helped.

Comment: My pleasure :-)